# Send named function to another function

Tags: string, go, anonymous-function

I am reading this lesson https://gobyexample.com/collection-functions and I see next code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func Any(vs []string, f func(string) bool) bool {
    for _, v := range vs {
        if f(v) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {

    var strs = []string{"peach", "apple", "pear", "plum"}

    fmt.Println(Any(strs, func(v string) bool {
        return strings.HasPrefix(v, "p")
    }))

}
```

With anonymous function it's working fine. But how to use named function there? I've tried:

```
...
    fmt.Println(Any(strs, strings.HasPrefix("p")))
```

But getting:

```
./prog.go:96:41: not enough arguments in call to strings.HasPrefix
    have (string)
    want (string, string)
./prog.go:96:41: cannot use strings.HasPrefix("p") (type bool) as type func(string) bool in argument to Any
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not passing a function, you're passing the output of a function, and you're not even calling `strings.HasPrefix` properly. If you have a function with signature `(string) bool`, you can just pass its name. eg: `Any(strs, strings.ToLower)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any()` expects a function value of type `func (string) bool`, but [`strings.HasPrefix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix) has type `func (string, string) bool`. It can't be passed directly.

That's why you used a function literal in the first place: to pass a function value that has the proper type.

If you would have a named function with exactly this signature, you could pass it:

```
func check(s string) bool {
    return strings.HasPrefix(s, "p")
}
```

And using it:

```
fmt.Println(Any(strs, check))
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bgB7oaEbV8r)):

```
true
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change `Any()` func to work with `type func (string, string) bool`?

Comment: @ipeacocks You can change `Any()` to expect any function type, question is if it makes sense. `strings.HasPrefix()` requires a second prefix argument, you have to provide that somewhere.